# Etymology of the word "remove"

Tags: etymology

What is the origin of the word "removed?"  It appears to have the prefix "re-", which generally means "repeating something again," although that does not seem to fit.  "Moving again" would actually be the opposite of removing something - it would suggest continuing to utilize it as opposed to deleting or destroying it.

Comment: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=Emove

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the noun form of the word (e.g. "He sat at some remove") will help.  *Remove* comes to Eng. from Fr. *removoire* and L. *re-* + *movere* (see [online etymology dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=remove)  In this context, *re-* is a prefix meaning "again," or "away," and the morphological combination means "to move away."  One *removes* something by *moving it away*.